# Why are unicorn creating multiple master processes on startup in production mode?

Tags: unicorn, production

Okay so im trying to setup a production serven with unicorn.

When i try to start the unicorn server thru the script i have written it starts up 2 master instance.

This only happens when i start it with the "-E production" given.

The init scipt that i start unicorn with:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/application/path/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && cd $APP_ROOT && bundle exec unicorn -D -E production -c $APP_ROOT/config/production/unicorn.rb"
action="$1"
set -u

old_pid="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
        test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
        test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
start)
        sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        su -s /bin/bash -c "$CMD" - www-data
        ;;
stop)
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
force-stop)
        sig TERM && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
restart|reload)
        sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -s /bin/bash -c "$CMD" - www-data
        ;;
upgrade)
        if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
        then
                n=$TIMEOUT
                while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
                do
                        printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
                done
                echo

                if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
                then
                        echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
                        exit 1
                fi
                exit 0
        fi
        echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
        su -s /bin/bash -c "$CMD" - www-data
        ;;
reopen-logs)
        sig USR1
        ;;
*)
        echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Uncorn config:

```
working_directory "/application/path/current"
pid "/application/path/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/application/path/current/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/application/path/current/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/application/path/current/tmp/unicorn.application_name.sock"
worker_processes 1
timeout 30

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end
```

Would realy appreciate any help!

Edit:
Hum... it appears as tough if i write the command "ps aux | grep unicorn" it only states 2 processes (1 master and 1 worker) but then why dos htop state that i have 5 processes active (2 masters and 3 workers)?

Comment: Same issue here... I guess it is related to `htop`

Answer (score 4):

`htop` lists each thread of a process separately, while `ps` doesn't. Please read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10403/53900) for more details.